# Pass a randomly generated function result into a setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, variables

I have a function that selects a random value from an array. The values represent the speed of a setTimeout, and I’m trying (and failing) to properly pass that value into the setTimeout. When I console.log it out, it returns random values from the array, but it’s not behaving as expected.

Here’s the relevant code (the section I'm trying to replace with the result of a function is currently called flashArray[k] - hopefully showing up in bold):

```
var k;
var flashArray = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000];

function speed() {
    var k = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)
    console.log(flashArray[k])
    return flashArray[k];
  }

function showCircle(item, j) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var num = initArray[j];
    var element = document.getElementById(num)
    element.classList.add("glow")
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      element.classList.remove("glow")
    }, 400);
    j++;
  }, **flashArray[k]** * j);
};
function showEachCircle(captureUserClicks) {
  initArray.forEach(showCircle);
  }
```

To be clear, this is not the only variation I’ve tried on this code - currently the variables k and flashArray are declared outside the function, and I’ve tried declaring within too.
The expected behaviour is that something (a graphic or colour change, say) appears and disappears, then moves on to the next iteration of initArray at whatever speed is passed to the function (the value of flashArray[k]). This works fine when it’s just a number I've inputted manually, but when using this method all iterations of the forEach loop happen at the same time.

I've also tried generating a random number and using toFixed for use in the setTimeout function, but again I've not had success here - the same behaviour, whereby all the 'flashes' (colour change or similar graphical motif, for example) happen at the same time, as opposed to one after the other.

The second requirement of this function is to pass in a new result for each iteration of the forEach loop.

Comment: where do you call the function speed ?
(also use let not var)

Comment: I see it's not in this code, but I had been attempting to call it from within the showCircle() function - specifically, I need a new result for each iteration of the forEach loop.

Comment: I guess you try this: 
 `speed() * j;` ?
and its returning to you the same number every time ?

Comment: I'd have put money on not being allowed to use a function like that... but it worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: I would appreciate it if you accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this:

`speed() * j`

it should work